# php - replace %20, %2D in urls

Tags: php, url

Original string (How to make a sandwich?).

how to make a url that looks like this `(how%20to%20make%20a%20sandwich%F2)` to appear like this `(how-to-make-a-sandwich?)` in php.

I know that `str_replace` can do this but it doesn't work in all cases.

I want to use something considered as best practice and works in all cases.

Thanks!

Comment: In what cases `str_replace` doesn't work?

Comment: Do you want hyphens or spaces between the words?

Comment: I want hyphens between words

Comment: did you mean `%3F` in your example? `%F2` is an accented character. So `str_replace(' ', '-', urldecode($str))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` is an efficient way to do it by replacing both values at the same time:

```
<?php
$string = "how%20to%20make%20a%20sandwich%F2";
$find = array( '/%20/','/%F2/' );
$replace = array( '-','?' );
echo preg_replace( $find, $replace, $string );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the build in php function:

`$str = urldecode( string $str)`

function. That convert ever %## to the corresponding char.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the simplest, cleanest way of doing it. And it uses str_replace, of course.

```
$test = urldecode("how%20to%20make%20a%20sandwich%F2");
$test = str_replace(" ", "-", $test);
```